# IMU Sensor not working when enabling lockstep in Gazebo 11

Tags: gazebo, ros-noetic, gazebo-11, gazebo-sensor

I have a robot with an IMU sensor (using libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so). When I Gazebo, it generates IMU messages on the appropriate topic. I'm trying to do visual-inertial odometry, so I need the IMU and camera to be well synchronized. The `--lockstep` option seems perfect for this. When I run Gazebo with the `--lockstep` option, however, it does not output any IMU messages. There don't appear to be any errors, either in the console output or the gazebo logs.

I am using Gazebo 11.11.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS noetic.

Here is the relevant section of the urdf file:

```xml
  <gazebo reference="${namespace}/base_link">
    </sensor>
    <sensor name="imu" type="imu">
      <always_on>true</always_on>
      <update_rate>300</update_rate>
      <visualize>true</visualize>
      <topic>__default_topic__</topic>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_imu_sensor.so" name="imu_plugin">
        <topicName>/multirotor/imu/ros</topicName>
        <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
        <updateRateHZ>300.0</updateRateHZ>
        <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
        <xyzOffset>0 0 0</xyzOffset>
        <rpyOffset>0 0 0</rpyOffset>
        <frameName>multirotor</frameName>
        <initialOrientationAsReference>false</initialOrientationAsReference>
      </plugin>
      <pose>0 0 0 3.14159265359 0 0</pose>
    </sensor>
  </gazebo>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out.

The IMU sensor does not work in lockstep in Gazebo 11.11.0. [This pull request](https://github.com/gazebosim/gazebo-classic/pull/3353) fixes the issue. I patched in two lines from it and the IMU sensor started working. I will switch to gazebo 11.14 for future work, which has the fix.